# Why does indentation immediately after a section heading not work?

Tags: sectioning, indentation

When I start a section and attempt to indent the first paragraph with `\indent`, the command has no effect:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

  % Section 0

    \indent Paragraph 1. % indented

    \noindent Paragraph 2.

  \section{Section 1}

    \indent Paragraph 1. % not indented

    \noindent Paragraph 2.

  \section{Section 2}

    \leavevmode\indent Paragraph 1. % indented

    \noindent Paragraph 2.

\end{document}
```

I found that `\leavevmode\indent` solves the problem (as does `\indent\indent`), but why is this happening in the first place?

Comment: With `\usepackage{indentfirst}` in the preamble, no `\indent` or `\leavevmode` command is needed.

Comment: It is not that it doesn't work it is that LaTeX goes to some effort to ensure that you do not get indentation in that position, as that is the normal typographical convention in at least some countries.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle See the edited code ("Section 0"): it's surprising that `\indent` works in a sectionless place but not after a section heading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Also, I've always thought of `\indent` and `\noindent` as manual overrides; shouldn't they *always* work? The user will think of them as if they toggled a bit that is being inspected when a new paragraph is started. I know that this isn't how these two actually work, but it's unexpected that `\indent\indent` gives double indentation. I would have expected it to be a sort of "indentation ensurer" so that there is no harm in having `\indent` at the end of a macro and calling it again paragraph-initially. Similarly, shouldn't `\indent` be forbidden inside a paragraph?

Comment: It shouldn't be surprising, anyway `\indent` does work, like all your `\indent` examples it is redundant as the paragraph indentation is automatic. The heading code _removes_ the indentation box, so it isn't that `\indent` doesn't work, it is that the indentation however added is suppressed after a heading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay - why do `\indent` and `\noindent` not set a binary flag? I've always understood them to work as if they were named `\ensureindent` and `\ensurenoindent`. This is confusing, why can't one add such `ensure`-macros and use those instead?

Comment: TeX primitives are handed down from Knuth:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle LaTeX3?

Comment: overriding the class design by explicit spacing commands in the document should be a non-goal of any document markup system.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, the question then is why `\indent` and `\noindent` exist in the first place. If they exist, they serve a function, but this function is achieved in an unexpected manner. So one might as well define a manual override that uses a flag. Also if working with templates were without problems (in that we never needed to adjust anything), everybody would be perfectly content with LaTeX2e and neither resort to plain TeX nor be interested in LaTeX3 :-)

Comment: well be happy some _very kind person_ wrote the `indentfirst` package to make the problem go away:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am glad, but I think there was just another *very kind person, except of course not as kind as the other one* making an awesome LaTeX3 feature request. It's the sort of thing I'd build in if I could rewrite TeX. I never know to what extent such things will happen and what the scope of LaTeX3 is with regard to such things. (The latter is a serious question, I'm not joking.)

Comment: The system is getting cross with us so I'll stop here, but you need to remember that latex3 like 2e is being written in TeX using the same primitives, so some things will be different, but some will be the same.

Comment: @LoverofStructure The LaTeX3 `xgalley` module does indeed use a flag here. What you are actually after though is a different template for the section headings (we'll still set the flag to suppress indents after section, as standard). Parts of this mechanism are set up, others still need work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\setlength\parindent{24pt}` to automatically indent all your paragraphs. So you don't have to `\indent` every time you start a new paragraph.

Comment: No this will not have any effect after a section heading by default.