# How to correctly indent a paragraph

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

I want to indent a paragraph so that each new line of it starts from the same position as shown below:

```
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
```

The `LaTeX` code below generates paragraph indented as follows:

```
  line 1
line 2
line 3
```

How can it be corrected?

**LaTeX**:

```
\section*{\hspace{150pt} Motivation}
\hspace{10pt}\begin{normalsize}
tagging conventions to define the general structure of a document (such as    
article, book, and letter), to stylise text throughout a document (such as 
bold and italic), and to add citations and cross-referencing. A TeX 
distribution such as TeXlive or MikTeX is used to produce an output file 
(such as PDF or DVI) suitable for printing or digital distribution.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your 'document' contains some 'errors'. `\begin{normalsize}` is wrong in the sense that `\normalsize` is a font size switch, but no environment. Normally, a paragraph directly after a section heading isn't indented. Use `\section*{\centering Motivation}\leavevmode` and an empty line, remove `\hspace{...}` and then continue with `tagging`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer would u please tell me how to fix that error

Comment: Actually, your question is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118165/why-does-indentation-immediately-after-a-section-heading-not-work, which is a duplicate of -http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/how-can-i-indent-the-paragraphs-which-follow-a-heading -- you will find the answer there

Comment: Reading your question again: Do you want to remove the indentation -- your 'examples' are contradicting, actually

Comment: Remove `\hspace{10pt}` if you don't want the paragraph to be indented by `10pt`. And, get rid of the redundant and ill-formed instruction `\begin{normalsize}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The environments are thought to be used that way too. In this case there's no need for normalsize since it's redundant, but one can use any other macro there.

Comment: Is the goal to indent every paragraph, without any vertical space between consecutive paragraphs?

Comment: @Elpharaoh Problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

I give it a try:

### Standard Behaviour

The standard paragraph shows an **indentation** in the **first line** and no space between paragraphs (`\parskip` is zero).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Standard Document Class Solution

You can use the `parskip` package ([CTAN link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip)) to solve your problem.

From the documentation:

> Package to be used with any document class at any size. It produces
>   the following Paragraph Layout:
>
> **Zero Parindent and non-zero Parskip.
>   The stretchable glue in `\parskip` helps LaTeX in finding the best place
>   for page breaks.**
>
> In addition, **the package adjusts the skips between
>   list items**.
>
> This package is no more than quick fix; the ‘proper’ way to achieve
>   effects as far-reaching as this is to create a new class. An example
>   class is to be found in the `ntgclass` set: `artikel3.cls`
>
> The `koma-script` bundle classes and the `memoir` class all provide
>   similar functionality, and their respective documentation files
>   discuss the pros (such as they are) and cons of this approach.

```
\documentclass{article}

% new package
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindlist{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Bad Solution: Manually Change the Lengths

Important for you is that the package `parskip` takes care of other things too. Sometimes you see people manually changing the parameters like `\setlength{\parindent}{0em}` and `\setlength{\parskip}{1em}` but this is considered bad because it also could change the distance between items in lists and so on. But I am not an expert here.

### Alternative Solution: KOMA Approach

There are the so called KOMA-Script ([CTAN link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)) document classes (in contrast to the standard document classes like article and book).

They offer a document class option called `parskip` which also "takes care of everything".

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindlist{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

PS: I don't get the

```
\section*{\hspace{150pt} Motivation}
\hspace{10pt}\begin{normalsize}
```

part of your code.