# Remove indent/space left of tcolorbox box

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, tcolorbox, parskip, parindent

I am using `tcolorbox` package for creating attractive definition and theorem blocks. But I am facing a problem right now.

If `tcolorbox` is placed immediately after chapter, section, subsection everything is ok. However, other tcolorboxes in the document have "paragraph-style" left spacing.

[image]

How to remove these spaces (they look awful and also generate a lot of "bad box" warnings)?

Example:

```
\subsection{Синус и тангенс}
%%% Okay here
\begin{definition}[label={def:sinalpha}]
    \textbf{Синус} острого угла $\alpha$ прямоугольного треугольника --- отношение катета, лежащего напротив этого угла, к гипотенузе.
\end{definition}

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\sin(\alpha) = \frac{BC}{AB}}
\end{equation}
%%% Awful spacing
\begin{definition}[label={def:sinalpha}]
    \textbf{Синус} острого угла $\alpha$ прямоугольного треугольника --- отношение катета, лежащего напротив этого угла, к гипотенузе.
\end{definition}
```

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank you! Both variants work fine but the first one removes paragraph spaces at all (well it is guessable from package's name).

Comment: I will turn the comment into an answer and then you can accept it. Next time provide a better example please (with documentclass and so on, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your problem is related to `parskip` and `parindent`.

1. If `\usepackage{parskip}` helps than that's an indication that the assumption is correct.
2. You could **alternatively** put an `\noindent` before each box

See also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285042) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55015) question.

Comment: @Downvoters I don't see any reason for a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

For a more scalable approach, you can try to define your `tcolorbox` environment with the option `before upper={\parindent0em}`. An even more global approach would be:

> \tcbset{before upper={\parindent0em}}

before defining any new `tcolorbox` environment.