# How to adjust a box position with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, tikz-styles, geometry, adjustbox, textwidth

I would like to adjust the position of a box created with tcolorbox by respecting the values of the horizontal margin on each of the two sides.
For instance : I would like to avoid the box to appear like this :

[image]

I have specified `width = \textwidth` but I don't understand why the result appears like this...

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, adjustbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries, width = \textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[before=\adjustbox{valign=t}\bgroup, after=\egroup]
\textbf{A retenir}
Bla-bla-bla
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I have specified the margin size with the line `\geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1.5cm}` but it seems like it's not respected by the box adjustment.

Thank you for your help,

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `tcolorbox` but your `geometry` specifications and your `width` specification. This is how the ouput looks:

[image]

From the image you can see that the box is indeed as wide as the text, but has a `\parindent` at the start. To fix this, simply change the width to `width = \linewidth-\parindent`. This produces:

[image]

To fix get rid of the `\parindent` to the left of the box, simply use `\noindent` before the box environment.

[image]

Also: here is a link to specifications of `geometry`: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins

Comment: Thank you @Vebjorn : actually I have already seen this documentation but didn't understand it well. For instance the last figure of the `\layout` shows different dimensions but what is `\geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1.5cm}` really fixing ? Is it n°3 `\oddsidemargin` or something else ? Also what is `\parindent` please ?

Comment: `\parindent` is the space (indent) on the first line in the paragraph. I guess hmargin is the horisontal margin (on both sides, total horisontal margin) and vmargin is the vertical margin (on top and bottom). I use `left=` and `right=` to fix the margins.

Comment: How do you think it would be possible to have the same values on both sides of the box equal to the values of hmargin ? (instead of putting parindent)

Comment: Try `\noindent` before the box. See this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337771/remove-indent-space-left-of-tcolorbox-box